# Can we use Spring data JPA to access StarRocks db

Tags: spring, jpa, starrocks

I want to write restful api using StarRocks db

I am trying to access StarRocks db table from spring data jpa. It works fine when the PK is single column. It fails for composite PK. Below is the sql generated by mysql dialect.

query:
select
c1_0.account,
c1_0.campaign_id,
c1_0.channel,c1_0.
campaign_name,
c1_0.status from channel_campaign c1_0
where
(c1_0.account,c1_0.campaign_id,c1_0.channel) in ((?,?,?))

starrocks-table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS channel_campaign (
channel         STRING,
account         STRING,
campaign_id     STRING,
campaign_name   STRING,
status          STRING
)
PRIMARY KEY (channel, account, campaign_id)
DISTRIBUTED BY HASH (channel);

Query throws below exception
JDBC exception executing SQL [select c1_0.account,c1_0.campaign_id,c1_0.channel,c1_0.campaign_name,c1_0.status from channel_campaign c1_0 where (c1_0.account,c1_0.campaign_id,c1_0.channel) in ((?,?,?))] [Getting syntax error at line 1, column 164. Detail message: Unexpected input ''ac1'', the most similar input is {'SELECT', 'WITH', '('}.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]

Comment: What is the generated SQL that will be executed?